# Create folders in Outlook via OLE automation (VFP or VB)

Tags: vb.net, ole, visual-foxpro

I would like to add some new folders alongside the InBox, Send, Trash folders using OLE Automation.  My preferred language is VFP, but VB might be useful too.

Here is how far I have dug into the Application object to ferret this out.

```
    loApp = CREATEOBJECT("outlook.application")
loSpace = loApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
UU = ""
FOR EACH loFolder IN loSpace.Folders
    IF  NOT LOWER(loFolder.Name)$"outlook data file  archives   wek@santaclaus.com "
        *? "______________________________"
        *? loFolder.Name
        *? CHR(9)+"-----"
        IF LOWER(loFolder.NAME) = LOWER("davidcosmos@metaworld.com")
            ? loFolder.NAME         && This is where the Accounts 
            FOR EACH loSubFolder IN loFolder.Folders
                ? CHR(9)+loSubFolder.Name+"-----"
                SET STEP ON
                IF loSubFolder.Name = "Inbox"
                    FOR EACH Email IN loSubFolder.Items
                        * Here the Email object represents each Email
                    ENDFOR 
                ELSE 
                ENDIF
           ENDFOR
        ELSE    
        ENDIF 
    ELSE 
    ENDIF    
ENDFOR
```

- I assume that the creation of folders should be done at the loSubFolder layer.

loSubFolder.

Any good idea would great...

TIA

DK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as using the Folders.Add method, here's the Excel VBA link but the method should also be available in OLE:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/folders-add-method-outlook

So, in your case, you would find the folder (or sub-folder, which is still a folder) that you want to add a new folder to, and call something along the lines of:

```
loSubFolder.Folders.Add("new folder name")
```

If you don't specify a second parameter in the Add method, it will create a folder that holds the same types of items as its parent, in this case the type of items in loSubFolder.

You can also specify a second parameter that is one of several explicitly specified OlDefaultFolders constants, for example:

```
loSubFolder.Folders.Add("new folder name", olFolderInbox)
```

Comment: I was able to add a folder into both levels as you specified.  Thank you.  Now I just have to figure out how to move selected Emails into those folders.  But it might be better to create a new question for that.  Thank you for the help.  My apology for the delayed response...

Answer (score 1):

In the following code we are adding 2 folders, 1 under default inbox, other at the same level as the inbox itself. Also note that, you might have multiple stores and thus multiple inboxes, we are using the store where the default inbox is.

```
#Define olFolderInbox   6

Local oOutlook As 'Outlook.Application', ;
    oNameSpace As 'Outlook.NameSpace', ;
    oMailFolder As 'Outlook.MAPIFolder', ;
    oTopFolder As 'Outlook.MAPIFolder'

Local lcFolderName1, lcFolderName2
lcFolderName1 = "My Dummy Folder - inbox"
lcFolderName2 = "My Dummy Folder"

m.oOutlook = createobject("Outlook.Application")
m.oNameSpace = m.oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

m.oMailFolder = m.oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder( olFolderInbox )
m.oTopFolder = m.oMailFolder.Parent

If Type("m.oMailFolder.Folders(m.lcFolderName1).Name") != 'C'
    m.oMailFolder.Folders.Add(m.lcFolderName1, olFolderInbox)
Endif
If Type("m.oTopFolder.Folders(m.lcFolderName2).Name") != 'C'
    m.oTopFolder.Folders.Add(m.lcFolderName2, olFolderInbox)
Endif
MessageBox('Done')
```

Note: For this to work, Outlook should not be running already. You might wish to wrap with try..catch...endtry. I wouldn't suggest using GetObject to overcome that and I really doubt that it would work anyway (I never suggest using GetObject with any COM for whatsoever).

Note2: If you need a folder other than where default inbox is then you could get it like:

```
m.MyFolder = m.oNameSpace.Folders("My Desired Folder")
```

Comment: I really appreciate the elaboration.  The problem I have is that this is good for someone who has only one Email account.  I have 20+ Accounts.  And I need move Emails into the New folders as per need.  How can I navigate to the proper Account or Email address?

Comment: I don't know how to change accounts.